# How to get master table data in slave table data has many relationship laravel 6 resources

Tags: php, json, laravel

I have two tables, User(master) and Product(slave) and the model looks like this

**User Model:**

```
class User extends Authenticatable {
    protected $fillable = [
       'name', 'email', 'password', 'api_token', 'role_id', 'no_telpon'
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
       'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

   public function products()
   {
      return $this->hasMany('App\Product');
   }
}
```

**Product Model:**

```
class Product extends Model
{
  protected $table = 'products';

  protected $guarded = ['id'];

  protected $fillable = [
    'nama_produk',
    'user_id',
    'description'
  ];

 public function user()
 {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
 }
}
```

And the resources of the Product looks like this

```
public function toArray($request) {
  return [
    'id' => $this->id,
    'nama_produk' => $this->nama_produk,
    'user_id' => $this->user_id,
    'description' => $this->description
  ]
}
```

The controller has a function that get all the products

```
public function index()
{
    try {
        $data = new ProductCollection(Product::all());
        return response()->json($data);
    } catch (\Throwable $th) {
        return response()->json($th);
    }
}
```

My issue is the user_id in the ProductResource is returning a number(id) because it has a relationship with User table, I want the result returning something like this

```
{
  {
    "id":1,
    "nama_produk": "Bakso Goreng",
    "user_id": {
       "id":"1",
       "name":"Andi",
       "email":"andi@gmail.com",
       "no_telpon":"00998422122"
    },
    "description":"Makanan berat"
  }
}
```

So there is a nested in user_id that has data from the user that add the product, not only a number(id), How do I do that?

UPDATE

This is my ProductCollection

```
class ProductCollection extends ResourceCollection
{
  public function toArray($request)
  {
    return ProductResource::collection($this->collection);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
public function index()
{
    try {
        $data = new ProductCollection(Product::with('user')->all());
        return response()->json($data);
    } catch (\Throwable $th) {
        return response()->json($th);
    }
}
```

EDIT:

```
public function toArray($request) {
  return [
    'id' => $this->id,
    'nama_produk' => $this->nama_produk,
    'user_id' => $this->user_id,
    'user' => $this->user,
    'description' => $this->description
  ]
}
```

OR

```
public function toArray($request) {
  return [
    'id' => $this->id,
    'nama_produk' => $this->nama_produk,
    'user_id' => $this->user,
    'description' => $this->description
  ]
}
```

Comment: it is still returning only the id of the user, but not the rest of the data

Comment: can you show me your ProductCollection class? if you dd() just Product::with('user')->all() you should see the user data

Comment: btw you shouldn't even need the ProductCollection you just can take the result of Product::with('user')->all() and put it in your json response

Comment: Reinett  i've upadated my question